# How can I use FolderBrowserDialog in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm looking for a way to select a specific directory in C#.

I already tried to use Folder Browser Dialog from the Toolbox but i could not find it there.

```cs
DialogResult result = FolderBrowserDialog1.dialog();
if(result==DialogResult.OK)
{
    txtPfad.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
}
```

Comment: Is this a *Windows Forms* application?

Comment: Yes, i think so

Comment: .net core or .net framework?

Comment: it is .net Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.fbdSave = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();`

as seen in https://github.com/ImaginaryDevelopment/imaginary-hero-designer/blob/ca58a983ac7346679ee5bf03fda9b738b80e4561/Hero%20Designer/Forms/OptionsMenuItems/frmCalcOpt.Designer.cs#L169

It lives in the System.Windows.Forms assembly https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/FolderBrowserDialog.cs,3af864744f155c13

Comment: Thank you very much for the second link now it works :D

Answer (score 3):

```
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var folderDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        DialogResult result = folderDialog.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string folderPath = folderDialog.SelectedPath;
            //Use folder path
        }
        else
        {
            //Operation aborted by the user
        }
    }
}
```

You must add also a using to System.Windows.Forms, if you don't see the namespace you must add a reference to the System.Windows.Forms DLL. Follow these steps on Visual Studio 2019:

1. Open the Solution Explorer Window
2. Right click on your project
3. Add/Reference...
4. Select System.Windows.Forms in the Asseblies/Framework section
5. Press OK

Answer (score 0):

Try change de implementation, rather then use dialog, try showDialog like this:

```cs
public void ChooseFolder()  
{  
    if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)   
    {  
        textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;  
    }  
}
```

EDIT: to create a FolderBrowserDialog control at design-time, you simply drag and drop a FolderBrowserDialog control from Toolbox to a Form in Visual Studio. After you drag and drop a FolderBrowserDialog on a Form, the FolderBrowserDialog looks like this Figure

[image]